# How to modify a Symfony web app to 'Web Api + AngularJS'?

Tags: angularjs, symfony, asp.net-web-api

I keep hearing 'web api' driven web development. So I have a symfony web app, how to modify it to be 'Web API'? just to replace the View part of the frontend app and backend app to use AngularJS? Then in each controller class, just encode all view data into Json string? Then all the symfony View part stuff like slot, partials, etc are not needed anymore?

Is it worthing doing this? Or web api is mainly just for mobile apps?(normally people just create a new application in symfony for mobile apps)

Comment: look at https://api-platform.com/ a symfony2 platform for APIs

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know this before!